# beautiful soup url with # in it

Tags: python-3.x, url, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a website with `?, =, #` in the URL. When I do I get redirected. I think I have narrowed the problem character to the `#`. I think it is trying to percent encode the `#`. In my case it is not an anchor, its sorting items across many pages
EDIT: I think it is *requests* that is causing the error, and that the # is typically a client only parameter, that is not being sent to the server

Working URLs

> www.foo.com/
>
> www.foo.com/example
>
> www.foo.com/example/search?q=&%5B%5D

Bad URLs (all pull up the same non-erroring page, even in browser)

> www.foo.com/example/#page1
>
> www.foo.com/example/%23page1    (percent encoded #)
>
> www.foo.com/example/something_that_does_not_exsit

```
response = requests.get(r"www.foo.com/example/#page1")
response.url
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this out? Might be useful, look into Selenium.

> [Beautifulsoup and link with a hash #](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128943/beautifulsoup-and-link-with-a-hash)

Comment: I would prefer not to use Selenium, maybe I'm missing something but its causing other issues

Comment: I am trying my best, having troubles with Selenium